# Animate widget on unmount

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom sheet that slides out of the bottom of the screen when mounted.

I was wondering, is there a way to play the animation backward when this widget gets unmounted by its parent?

So effectively, is it possible to animate a widget that is no longer in the widget tree?

Comment: I think the answer is just no. Maybe you can do it on dispose right before the end.